# SSAS Browser does not show any hierarchies/groups

Tags: ssas

Good morning everyone,

I am new to BI dev and therefore a beginner in SSAS. I set up my dimensions and everything looks fine within the Dimension Browser! For example: Within the date dimension it show the year -> quarter -> month -> date as a drill down menu below the "all" root element.

But I am confused. When I use the Cube Browser and I try add the date dimension it is not grouped automatically as I would expect (such as Year/Quarter/Month). Everything is just added as single rows (no drill down possible).

How can I achieve a drill down behavior? What am I doing wrong? I guess I need to change some properties. But which ones? I expect that I set up the attribute relationships within the dimensions correctly.

I am glad for any help.

Comment: How did you set your KeyColumns? Could be that it is taking all columns of rows in your hierarchy as unique, and not grouping them - thus you are not having the desired drill down effect.

Comment: I tried setting them up in several ways. 
a) All columns (such as Month, Quarter, Year) reflect the dateKey-columns
b) Column keys are set to a combination: e.g. for quarter I used; quarter + year as key collection.

But none of those approaches worked :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the IsAggregatable of each attribute is set to true, and also in your hierarchy start with Year, then Quarter, then Month. You can start without configuring the KeyColumns in the attributes for the calendar dimension, and if it still doesn't group the records configure the KeyColumns for Year, having Quarter and Month, Quarter having Month...

Checkout this link which briefs the use of aggregation, and attribute relationships in more detail. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2567/ssas--best-practices-and-performance-optimization--part-3-of-4/

Your calendar dimension should look something like this
[image]

Attributes should be setup like this
[image]

For a more detailed article, go through this link which elaborates on the calendar dimension and how it should be setup. http://duncansutcliffe.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/a-better-date-dimension-modelling-in-analysis-services/

Comment: IsAggregatbalbe is set to true, my hierarchy starts with year -> quarter -> month

I also tried to configure the key columns in your suggeste way. Nothing is helping so far :/

Comment: I updated my answer. If that is the case, then most probably your calendar dimension, i.e. the source of the dimension in your DSV - could possibly have some issues.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all the hints but the problem is not fixable within the ssas cube browser. The interesting thing is, when I use excel, connect to the cube and use a pivot chart all groupings/hierarchies are viewed correctly. 

I have no clue about this bug, but all I need is a propper view for the end user. So, I guess my problem is solved in a wired way ;-) 

Thanks for the hints :)

Comment: I have the exact same problem! The data when browsing in cube's browser do not get grouped by the columns... If i analyse data on excel is working without any configuration. The problems seems to be something with the cube's datagrid! Any ideas?

Comment: It would be nice and helpful if you review my awnser as I had the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

After searching and testing for hours, I, finally found it!

The SSDT 2008 Cube's Browser control, had theese features, like, aggregating, grouping, drillthrough and setting on rows or/and on columns.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzBMgCMA_n4

The SSDT 2012, 2014, 2016 Cube's Browser controls, do not support theese features, as the previous control of 2008 was deprecated! Also the same thing happend on SQL Server Management Studio Browser when using analysis services.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lADpfxSl544

It seems that Microsoft is using the Excel Power Pivot instead in many articles when describing:

1) Grouping and aggregating:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189718.aspx

2) Drillthrough:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166579.aspx

Cris Webb has covered this change on his blog:

> The cube browser has now disappeared from SSDT, and is replaced by the
>   control used by the SSRS query generator. This is because the old
>   browser used the OWC control which was deprecated years ago and
>   finally had to be replaced; it’s a massive step backwards because this
>   control is truly awful: for example you can no longer put anything
>   other than Measures on columns in your query. Arrggghhh! I’ve started
>   using Excel instead, but Excel won’t always be available on some sites
>   and it’s a hassle to move to a different app to check your figures.

So, the only solution is to use the Excel Power Pivot for theese kind of features!